# How to make user input multiline string data in c++?

Tags: c++

I tried getline(cin, .... ), but this cannot take input more than one line. The end of input is determined by something like #.

Comment: How do you want the user to indicate the end of the input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use getline with a different character than '\n' as the delimeter.

```
// will collect input until the user enters a #
getline(cin,mystring,'#');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
#include <iostream>

...

std::string input;
while(1)
{
    input = "";
    std::cin >> input;
    if(input[input.size() - 1] == '#')
        break;
}
```

Use C++ stuff, not C stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just concatenate the strings for each line?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for `conio.h` (or whatever else your platform has if it doesn't have conio) and just write an input method myself. That way you can make it much prettier and foolproof.